# Select a Radio Button in a Fieldset Programatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a fieldset with radio(options to a question), I want to preselect a radio button in the options control group programatically on page show, here is the control group :

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="options">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optiona" value="a"
                                                           checked="checked" />
    <label for="optiona" id="labela">Ondo</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optionb" value="b" />
    <label for="optionb">Lagos</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optionc" value="c" />
    <label for="optionc">Abuja</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optiond" value="d" />
    <label for="optiond">Kogi</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optione" value="e" />
    <label for="optione">Niger</label>
</fieldset>
```

I have tried the following:

```
var sel = questions[indexNo].correct;
$("#option" + sel).prop("checked", true)
$("#option"+ sel).is(":checked");
```

Comment: How does questions object look like ?

Comment: Questions is an array object that looks like this question({'quest':"",'optionsa':"",'optionsb':"",'correct':""}), I dont think this is important cos what I am trying to do is keep track of the selected answer by a user per question when the user navigates to the question again his selection shld be preselected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/aawNj/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $( "#optiona" ).prop( "checked", false ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );    
    $( "#optionb" ).prop( "checked", true ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
});
```

or another working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/EFzxj/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $( "#optionb" ).prop( "checked", true );  
    $('#content').trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: This works but it does not clear a previously selected option, so you have 2 options selected in the control group, how do I clear all the selected options in the control group.

Comment: Take a better look at my example, both of them are clearing previous one. First one with "checked", false and second one with trigger('create'); of course trigger create MUST be executed on DIV with data-role="content". again, take a look at my examples, everything is there.

Comment: I need to deselect any radio button in this group before selecting the correct answer